# How to configure SAML response to pass attributes using xsi:type="xs:string" instead of xsi:type="xs:anyType" in G Suite?

Tags: mapping, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, google-workspace

I successfully setup SAML between Identity Provider(IdP) as Gsuite and service provider(SP). When i create user in G suite it is created in my app after first login as expected. Now i want to automatically populate user`s first name and last name  taken from Gsuite in corresponding fields in my app. I m trying to configure correct mapping for my application and G suite but it doesn't work, despite i did it successfully with other IdP such as Okta and Keycloak. Investigating, i noticed that SAML response from G Suite includes `<saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType"` while SAML response from Keycloak includes `<saml2:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string"`. I think problem in this place.
So my question, is there any means to configure passing **string** type instead of **anyType** in G suite? Can t find such info in settings and Gsuite guides.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no way to change it. We just added new parsing condition to our code.